# Debugging problem with GPIO serial pins

Tags: gpio, serial, uart, open-source

I've been trying to run a port of a small RTOS called ChibiOS on my Raspberry Pi, and am having trouble with the serial communications. Specifically, when I use a UART connected at 3.3V to the GPIO pins on the Pi, I can receive Tx from the Pi but it won't respond to anything sent over the Rx line. I saw on http://forum.chibios.org/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1334 that my problem could be due to using a faulty new release of bootcode.bin or start.elf and tried the version recommended on that forum, but it didn't work. I was wondering:

1) Is there somewhere I could get the source code to bootcode.bin or start.elf to examine, and then compile them myself? This might help me with debugging my problem.

2) What are some things I can do in order to better debug my problem?

EDIT:

*3)  Are there any similar situations you have experienced involving a nonfunctional Rx line which might point me toward the problem?*

Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 1):

For both bootcode.bin and start.elf, as best I can, source still isn't public.  While I wasn't able to find it explicitly stated, they appear to still part of the remaining "blob" talked about in the [rasp pi birthday post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/6299), though if you want to do a deep-dive [broadcom's bcm21553 driver release](http://blog.broadcom.com/chip-design/android-for-all-broadcom-gives-developers-keys-to-the-videocore-kingdom/) might have the parts you could build your way there.

There are a number of projects hinting at it:

- Unsure how complete the information is but [Herman Hermitage github](https://github.com/hermanhermitage) seems to have a bunch of info in that space (Lots of other sources point to that as the home of a reverse eng effort on Videocore CPU code, of which I believe bootcode.bin and start.elf are)
- In the same "unsure" place there is the [piface tool](https://cowlark.com/piface/doc/stable/doc/index.wiki), the docs make it clear the tool isn't very functional at this point, but it at least beings the process of opening up the Videocore CPU